# How to use sidebar for changing CarouselView's item position?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I'm thinking of displaying CarouselView's item names inside sidebar, and when one of the names is clicked, the CarouselView will change its current position, showing that chosen item's details.

The first thing which came into my mind is Shell Flyout's interface which visually fit with what I want, but from the documentation, Flyout is used to for page navigation in Shell.

How can I make this work? If not, is there any good alternative? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some functions for a default FlyoutMenu:

```
public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        flyoutPage.collectionView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you will want to apply the logic for your carousel
        //Will use position as an example
        var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FlyoutPageItem;
        yourCaourselView.Position = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you create this 'sidebar'? And 'too much' aside, is it possible to use Flyout view?

Comment: Yeah you can use the flyout, OnSelectionChanged, you can add whatever code you want for the action you desire. I guess personally I have always used Flyout for navigation only. I'll post example in my answer above.

Comment: Flyout comes with all the extra animations, and it pushes out like a navigation menu, that's why I suggested making your own 'sidebar' if you wish to customize it, and each one can be a button, each containing a 'position' of a preloaded carousel. Depending on how you have implemented your code.